# Error while installation of cx_oracle package on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server-2008-r2, cx-oracle

I am trying to setup Python Environment on windows server 2008 R2 along with cx-oracle package. Installed the 32 bit Python 3.8.0 successfully. But while installing the cx-oracle package through pip, getting error that “cannot build wheel” and “need visual c++ 14.0”.
Have installed visual c++ 14.0 (32 bit; tried 64 bit as well) but getting same error

Comment: It would be easier to use Python 3.7.  There are no cx_Oracle wheels for 3.8 yet.  You can see the available files at https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle/#files

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherJones for the suggestion. It worked but I have other issues related to Oracle client.

Comment: What other issues? What version of the Oracle Client libraries did you install?